# Close ports 1443

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

When I run `netstat -a` I see port 1443 as status `Listening`. I create a rule in the windows firewall to close ports and re-run netstat but I'm still seeing the ports in `Listening` status. What do I need to do to close these ports?

[image] [image]

Comment: You might want to clarify what your purpose is - stop TCP/IP connections from anywhere? stop all remote connections? You've just stopped remote connections on 1433, but you can still have local connections, and you can still connect to SQL Server on a different port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Firewall does not stop processes from listening on a port - instead it blocks outbound connections from attempting to connect to that port. Windows Firewall does not block localhost connections by default.

Also, for SQL Server itself, you should use the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" tool to change SQL Server's port bindings and to disable/enable specific interfaces (including TCP entirely if you want to use the Shared Memory or Named Pipes transports instead).